# gunicorn worker (gevent) failed to boot using python 3.11

Tags: python, gunicorn, gevent

We are using alpine 3.16.2, python 3.11.0 and pip 22.3 along with bunch of other libraries (django, google, etc.) installing via pip

```
gunicorn==20.1.0
gevent==22.10.2
greenlet==2.0.1

gunicorn worker (gevent) failed to boot, please find error details as below:

    
    [2022-11-30 09:19:27 +0000] [6] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
    [2022-11-30 09:19:27 +0000] [6] [INFO] Listening at: https://0.0.0.0:8443 (6)
    [2022-11-30 09:19:27 +0000] [6] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
    [2022-11-30 09:19:27 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
    [2022-11-30 09:19:28 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
    [2022-11-30 09:19:29 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
        worker.init_process()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 144, in init_process
        self.patch()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 38, in patch
        monkey.patch_all()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 1263, in patch_all
        patch_thread(Event=Event, _warnings=_warnings)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 200, in ignores
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 791, in patch_thread
        _patch_existing_locks(threading_mod)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 672, in _patch_existing_locks
        if isinstance(o, rlock_type):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    **ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists**
    [2022-11-30 09:19:29 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
    [2022-11-30 09:19:29 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
        worker.init_process()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 144, in init_process
        self.patch()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 38, in patch
        monkey.patch_all()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 1263, in patch_all
        patch_thread(Event=Event, _warnings=_warnings)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 200, in ignores
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 791, in patch_thread
        _patch_existing_locks(threading_mod)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 672, in _patch_existing_locks
        if isinstance(o, rlock_type):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    **ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists**
    [2022-11-30 09:19:29 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
    [2022-11-30 09:19:30 +0000] [6] [WARNING] Worker with pid 7 was terminated due to signal 15
    [2022-11-30 09:19:30 +0000] [6] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    [2022-11-30 09:19:30 +0000] [6] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Same is working fine using alpine 3.16.2, python 3.10.7 and pip 22.2.2 along with same bunch of other libraries (django, google, etc.) installing via pip

Could someone please help on this and please let me know if any other information is needed ?

Note:- Any insights on how to triage/debug this further is also helpful

Comment: Looks like they only test on 3.10 in CI currently: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/2f9eb19b666868d324150072e7489788688c91cb/.github/workflows/tox.yml#L9

Answer (score 1):

Try using 3.10. I think it's a problem with Python 3.11.  I spent half of a day trying to deploy a new project to Heroku.  Couldn't figure it out so I started from new and changing the python version to 3.10.9.  This worked, it works with 3.10.9.  I was receiving module not found errors on PROJECT_NAME.wsgi when deploying

According to this site, python 3.11 does not support gunicorn but it also says 3.10 doesn't support gunicorn.  https://pyreadiness.org/3.11/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out newrelic-admin and gevent don’t get along in this version of python (3.11) (we use like **run newrelic-admin gunicorn** with some configuration parameters **wsgi**)

We monkey-patched **gevent/monkey.py** to catch the ReferenceError that was being thrown and try to get as much info out of it as we could, then we saw the newrelic monkey-patch warning

So, we have removed **newrelic-admin** from run command and initializing the newrelic agent before the WSGI callable variable **application** (in wsgi.py) and it solved the issue for us